# Canvas too big for iPhone screen, wont resize with viewport tag

Tags: html, css, iphone, viewport, meta-tags

I have a webpage that draws a canvas with size width 960px and height 640px

I want to display this to fit on the iPhone4 screen . Its too big at the moment and has scroll bars.

I want to shrink it to fit on the screen

I have tried using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.5"/>
```

but it does not work.

Does anybody know how i can get it to fit on the iPhone4 screen?

Comment: Have you tried using percentages instead of pixels for the width and height?

Answer (score 1):

Im editing my post, im sory i havent seen detailed your question, but here it is

As Azrael says also mention about Pixels and Percentages, 
setting your canvas as "Pixels" will be a problem for your mobile website , because the viewport of mobile is only small , so saying 960PX for your width causes huge scrollbars cause your iphone cant show 960px, so make sure you use percentages for your page wrappers , something like this

```
#pageWrapper{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

and then your page content will be using media queries.

There are more guides and talks about making your site mobile ready be sure to check this following links

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Hope this helps